# Android: After a minute go back to main layout

Tags: java, android

I have 2 layout activity_main and activity_menu. I want code that When I dont push anything on activity_menu in 1 min go back to activity_main like Auto-lock in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the timer [code](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/)

then do the following.
1. if nothing is clicked after specific interval. call `onBackPressed();` if previous activity is MainActivity or desired activity. else go to desired activity n call finish ();
2. if any action performed then just restart or finish the timer.